# Reading Excel Files MSOffice vs Open Office

Tags: c#, excel, openoffice.org

I have an application the reads excels files and move them to my MS SQL database, via C#. This is a done on a machine that host the MSSQL Server as well as an IIS Arcgis Server. The machine is not very strong only 3gb of RAM and the prospects of them giving me a true server seem close to to nil. So I wanted to know which one option is less demanding , memory wise. OpenOffice or MS Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither - [use the OleDb provider](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx). It's much simpler and faster. But between the two options you proposed, MS Excel is almost certainly going to be less memory intensive.